# How to handle an undefined value with Angular string interpolation?

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular project and I have the following doubt about how correctly handle this situation where into a string interpolation defined into my template I can have undefined values. Into  the HTML code of a component I have:

```
<td>{{file.info.meta_data.type.type}}</td>
```

the **file.info.meta_data.type.type** can be **undefined** and cause the following exception in the Chrome console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at AssetDetailsComponent_ng_template_103_Template (asset-details.component.html:285)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:7457)
    at refreshView (core.js:7326)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:8427)
    at refreshView (core.js:7350)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:8427)
    at refreshView (core.js:7350)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:8427)
    at refreshView (core.js:7350)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8473)
```

How can I correctly handle this situation to show an empty string in case the previous field have an undefined value? Can I handle this directly with string interpolation or have I to use an *ngIf** directive on the **td** tag^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply check if it is undefined before

```
<td>{{file?.info?.meta_data?.type?.type}}</td>
```

it will show empty string if any value for `file`, `info`, `meta_data`, `type` is undefined

Answer (score 1):

Here it `?` will check for undefine if it is undefine display empty string and for value
display value :

```
<td>{{file.info.meta_data.type.type?file.info.meta_data.type.type:''}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add **?** to handle null or undefined cases.

```
<td>{{file?.info?.meta_data?.type?.type || '-'}}</td>
```

here '-' this will be default value when **file?.info?.meta_data?.type?.type** is undefined or null.